email login not working while logging through auth0 used in my project
I am using auth0 to login in to my project. I am able to do third-party login, through google, but unable to do the same from email and password, it is saying "WE'RE SORRY, SOMETHING WENT WRONG WHEN ATTEMPTING TO LOG IN". Same problem is with sign in.
here is part of my code implementing auth0:
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
const { user, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect, logout } = useAuth0();
if (isAuthenticated){
        console.log(user)
    }

    const loggingout = () => {
        logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: window.location.origin }})
        console.log("logged out")
    }

return (
        <>
            <div className='navBar'>

                <div className='additional-navitems-container'>
                    <div>
                        {isAuthenticated?(
                            <button className='button-logout' onClick={loggingout }>Log out</button>
                        ):(
                            <button className='button-loggin' onClick={() => loginWithRedirect() }>Sign In</button>
                        )}
                    </div>
                    <div className='profile-picture'>
                        {isAuthenticated?(
                            <img src={user.picture} alt='profile'></img>
                        ):(
                            <img src='' alt='profile images'/>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </>
    );
}

export default NavBar;


Screenshot of the login page
I tried to give "forget password" but the same problem is occurring there also.
I ask to solve this issues and make login and sign in possible by email and password
